# I want to input boolean value in ChallengeDto

Tags: spring

```
public class ChallengeDto {
    private Long id;
    private Category category;
    private String title;
    private String subTitle;
    private boolean like;
    private int totalScore;
    private int requiredScore;

    public ChallengeDto(Long id, Category category, String title, String subTitle, boolean like, int totalScore, int requiredScore) {
        this.id = id;
        this.category = category;
        this.title = title;
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
        this.like = like;
        this.totalScore = totalScore;
        this.requiredScore = requiredScore;
    }
}
```

I created challengeDto that include challenge's properties(id, category, title, subtitle, totalScore, requiredScore) and like property(can know that if i like challenge or not).
If I put like button, that information stored challengeLike table.

```
public class ChallengeLike {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "challenge_like_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "challenge_id")
    private Challenge challenge;

    private LocalDateTime createDate;
}
```

Now I'm trying to write a code to retrieve challengeDto that checks if I clicked like or not, but I'm having a problem... I can't think of what kind of code to make.

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ChallengeDtoRepository {

    private final EntityManager em;



    @Transactional
    public List<ChallengeDto> findChallenges(Long userId) {
        return em.createQuery(
                "select new " +
                        "com.example.candy.controller.challenge.ChallengeDto(c.id,c.category,c.title,c.subTitle,????,c.totalScore,c.requiredScore)" +
                        " from Challenge c" +
                        " left join ChallengeLike cl on c.id = cl.challenge.id" +
                        " and cl.user.id = : userId", ChallengeDto.class)
                .setParameter("userId", userId)
                .getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: where's your like property in challange_like table?

Comment: I didn't create a likeDone property, but set it up so that the information can be entered into challenge like entity only when I press like button. If the user does not press like button, no information will be entered into challengeLike at all. If I write the code like you, I'm worried that all non-like challenges will be saved as false in every user, and if this happens, the amount of data will be too big...

Comment: not necessarily. You will save the data in the Challenge_Like table only if a user hits a like. It will become false or will be deleted from that table if the user unlikes the post. So what you're worrying about here is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I misunderstood. I'd like to ask you one more question. The reason I created challengeDto is to show if the user liked it or not when the system sent all challenge lists created by admin to the user. However, I'm concerned that mapToDto (ChallengeLikex) can only create challengeDto with a like. The goal is to create challenge Dto for all challenges to see if the user pressed like or not.

Comment: Oh! I understand. That's simple too!
Implement `ChallengeRepository` exactly the way I've implemented `ChallengeLikeRepository` and modify the `mapToDto` accordingly. I'm updating my answer with the updated `mapToDo` method.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your quick and detailed answer. I learn a lot of things that I didn't think of. But the question is, when I look at mapToDto method, I wonder if they like it or not according to user. Suppose there are already challenge1, challenge2, challenge3, user1 only press "like" to challenge1, and user2 press "like" to challenge2. And if user1 wants to see challengeDto list, user1 will get challenge1 (true), challenge2 (false), challenge3 (false). Meanwhile, user2 receives challenge1 (false), challenge2 (false), challenge3 (true).

Comment: Finally I understood what you're trying to achieve. I've updated the answer one last time, please check now, and if you think that was helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to rename the field to `likeDone` or something different than `like`, it makes the code ambiguous.

However, just simply do:

```
cl.likeDone
```

which means:

```
return em.createQuery(
            "select new " +
                    "com.example.random.demo.dto.ChallengeDto(c.id,c.category,c.title,c.subTitle,cl.likeDone,c.totalScore,c.requiredScore)" +
                    " from Challenge c" +
                    " left join ChallengeLike cl on c.id = cl.challenge.id" +
                    " where cl.user.id = : userId", ChallengeDto.class)
            .setParameter("userId", userId)
            .getResultList();
```

However, try to use JPA if you don't have any mandatory condition to use native query or jpql.

**JPA implementation:**

```
@Repository
public interface ChallengeLikeRepository extends JpaRepository<ChallengeLike, Long> {
    List<ChallengeLike> findAllByUser_Id(long userId);
}
```

Just call the repository method from service layer and map to your required dto:

```
public List<ChallengeDto> findChallenges(Long userId) {
    List<ChallengeLike> entities = this.repository.findAllByUser_Id(userId);
    return entities.stream().map(this::mapToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The `mapToDto()` method converts the entity to corresponding `ChallengeDto`

```
private ChallengeDto mapToDto(ChallengeLike x) {
    return ChallengeDto.builder()
            .category(x.getChallenge().getCategory())
            .id(x.getChallenge().getId())
            .like(x.isLikeDone())
            .requiredScore(x.getChallenge().getRequiredScore())
            .subTitle(x.getChallenge().getSubTitle())
            .title(x.getChallenge().getTitle())
            .totalScore(x.getChallenge().getTotalScore())
            .userId(x.getUser().getId())
            .build();
}
```

For your convenience, some properties has been added or changed in some classes. The `@Builder` annotation has been added to the `ChallengeDto` class. The rest of the corresponding `entity` and other classes:

a) ChallengeLike.java

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ChallengeLike {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "challenge_like_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("challengeLikes")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "challenge_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("challengeLikes")
    private Challenge challenge;

    private boolean likeDone;

    private LocalDateTime createDate;
}
```

b) Challenge.java

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Challenge {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Category category;

    private String title;

    private String subTitle;

    private int totalScore;

    private int requiredScore;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "challenge", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("challenge")
    private List<ChallengeLike> challengeLikes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

c) Category.java

```
public enum Category {
    CAT_A,
    CAT_B
}
```

**Update**

If you want to fetch `Challenge` entity instead of `ChallengeLike` and map that to `ChallengeDto`, first implement `ChallangeRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface ChallengeRepository extends JpaRepository<Challenge, Long> {
}
```

Add the fetchType to EAGER in Challange Entity class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "challenge", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("challenge")
    private List<ChallengeLike> challengeLikes = new ArrayList<>();
```

And to map the `Challenge` to `ChallengeDto`, you can add another mothod as follows:

```
private ChallengeDto mapToDto(Challenge x) {
    return ChallengeDto.builder()
            .category(x.getCategory())
            .id(x.getId())
            .like(!x.getChallengeLikes().isEmpty() && x.getChallengeLikes().get(0).isLikeDone())
            .requiredScore(x.getRequiredScore())
            .subTitle(x.getSubTitle())
            .title(x.getTitle())
            .totalScore(x.getTotalScore())
            .userId(x.getUserId())    // if you have user reference in Challenge, remove this otherwise.
            .build();
}
```

finally, to incorporate everything properly, change the caller:

```
public List<ChallengeDto> findChallenges(Long userId) {
    List<Challenge> entities = this.repository.findAll();
    List<ChallengeDto> entitiesWithoutChallengeLikes = entities.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getChallengeLikes() == null 
                    || x.getChallengeLikes().isEmpty())
            .map(this::mapToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<ChallengeDto> entitiesInferredFromChallengeLikes = entities.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.getChallengeLikes() != null && !x.getChallengeLikes().isEmpty())
            .flatMap(x -> x.getChallengeLikes().stream())
            .map(this::mapToDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    entitiesInferredFromChallengeLikes.addAll(entitiesWithoutChallengeLikes);
    return entitiesInferredFromChallengeLikes;
}
```

**Final Update**

Well, I finally understood properly what you expected. Adopt the following changes to the previous solution and you will get exactly what you want.

Change the 2 occurrence of the following in the `findChallanges` method:

```
.map(this::mapToDto)
```

To:

```
.map(x -> mapToDto(x, userId))
```

And the two `mapToDto` functions will be changed to follows:

```
private ChallengeDto mapToDto(ChallengeLike x, long userId) {
    return ChallengeDto.builder()
            .category(x.getChallenge().getCategory())
            .id(x.getChallenge().getId())
            .like(x.getUser().getId() == userId && x.isLikeDone())
            .requiredScore(x.getChallenge().getRequiredScore())
            .subTitle(x.getChallenge().getSubTitle())
            .title(x.getChallenge().getTitle())
            .totalScore(x.getChallenge().getTotalScore())
            .userId(x.getUser().getId())
            .build();
}

private ChallengeDto mapToDto(Challenge x, long userId) {
    return ChallengeDto.builder()
            .category(x.getCategory())
            .id(x.getId())
            .like(false)
            .requiredScore(x.getRequiredScore())
            .subTitle(x.getSubTitle())
            .title(x.getTitle())
            .totalScore(x.getTotalScore())
            .userId(userId)
            .build();
}
```